# SparkPost additional field

Tags: php, sparkpost

I can´t get my head around syntax on line 25 in this SparkPost code - [link on github](https://github.com/SparkPost/php-sparkpost/blob/master/examples/transmissions/create_transmission.php)
What if I want to add an additional variable to this?

```
'substitution_data' => ['name' => 'YOUR_FIRST_NAME'],
```

Say I want to add `'company' => 'ABC'`

How should I change the code on line 25 to have multiple variables?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`substitution_data` is an arbitrary list of key/value pairs you can supply and then use in your content or template. In PHP you pass in `substitution_data` as an associative array. To add more items to it you can do this:

```
substitution_data' => [
    'name' => 'YOUR_FIRST_NAME',
    'company' => 'ABC',
],
```

Check out the [substitutions reference](https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/substitutions-reference.html) in the SparkPost docs for more information about substitution data and how to use it.